# I would like to develop an Asp.net web application with functionality to create the following in Office 365 E3:

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

We would like to develop an **Asp.net** application with functionality to create the following in Office 365 E3:
1. Create Labels and Retention policies in Web Application and write it to Labels in Office 365 E3.
2. Create Cases in web application and write these cases to Cases of eDiscovery

Can you please suggest how to achieve the above and if there is a list of API's which can be accessed to perform the above and similar functions in Security and Compliance Center of **Office 365 E3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mechanism I'm aware of to create Labels and Retention policies programatically is Powershell - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt587093(v=exchg.160).aspx

Note that "Labels" are called "Compliance Tags" in the commandlets.

Invoking powershell from a asp.net app is a pain but doable.
see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/ to get started.

Likewise the same set of commandlets provide the ability to create and manipulate e-discovery cases.